# how do i fix the "divide by zero" error i get when trying to run a crystal report looking at the number of orders delivered outside a given range?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

the report looks at the delivery date / time and the planned date / time working out a percentage within a given period

if the delivery is not updated for all orders then I get a "divide by zero" error 
formula is

```
IF {@ONTIME}<>0 
THEN 
1 % Count ({the job number}, {delivery address}) 
ELSE 
0
```

any suggestions please

Comment: You can write nested if like if count is 0 then don't do division else do division

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IF not isnull ({@ONTIME}) or  ({@ONTIME})<>0 then
1 % Count ({the job number}, {delivery address}) 
ELSE 
0
```